# Why only Google warn us about attackers?

Tags: malware, web-browser, google

There are so many search engines like ask.com, yahoo.com and many more, but only Google warn us about attackers. Why so?

[image: security warning]

Comment: I'm pretty sure firefox and probably most other modern browsers have this feature too: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-does-phishing-and-malware-protection-work

Comment: @thexacre My question not related to browsers. Even antivirus also have web security features. but my question is totally related to search engines only.

Comment: not every search engine runs malware checks on the sites it spiders

Comment: That is not a search engine warning, it comes from the browser.

Answer (score 4):

> There are so many search engines like ask.com, yahoo.com and many more, but only Google warn us about attackers. Why so?

Just because it says Google it does not mean it is related to the search engine.

[Google Safe Browsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Safe_Browsing) is a service run by Google, but it is not directly related to their search engine, same as Google Cloud, Youtube etc. are not directly related to the search engine either. Use of Google Safe Browsing is integrated into at least Chrome and Firefox.

The is a similar service for Microsoft browsers ([Microsoft SmartScreen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SmartScreen)), which is run by Microsoft and which is also not directly related to their search engine. Several security companies have similar services for their firewalls (i.e. blacklisting malicious sites) even though they don't have a search engine at all.